# Узнать текст InlineKeyboardButton в telebot

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Есть клавиатура(`db.view_all_coins(call.message.chat.id`) возвращает список).

```
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
for coin in db.view_all_coins(call.message.chat.id):
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=coin, callback_data='view_info'))
```

Текст для каждой кнопки генерируется из этого списка.
Как мне потом получить этот текст по нажатии на эту клавиатуру?
Пробовал `call.message.json['reply_markup']['inline_keyboard'][0][0]['text']` но мне нужно возвращать именно текст из нажатой кнопки, а не просто 1 элемент списка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы обрабатывать текст, ты можешь воспользоваться [*ReplyKeyboardMarkup*](https://surik00.gitbooks.io/aiogram-lessons/content/chapter5.html).
Если хочешь использовать именно *InlineKeyboardButton*, то можешь захватывать возвращаемую callback_data и находить по ней текст либо из объекта клавиатуры, который имеет структуру, либо задать [именнованный кортёж](https://habr.com/en/post/330034/) или словарь и записать туда callback_data и buttonText, после чего обращаться по callback_data и получать текст

```
{"inline_keyboard": 
[
    [{"text": "string", "callback_data": "string"}], 
    [{"text": "string", "callback_data": "string"}],
]}
```